# sudoers is world writable error

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, sudo

I changed the /ect file permissions on Ubuntu 12.10 so that i could edit bash.bashrc so that neo4j can see the JVM but now I am getting errors when i try run the neo4j server

I entered the code below and I managed to edit bash.bashrc but now i cant use sudo at all!

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /ect

sudo -u neo4j /home/neo4j-community-1.8/bin/neo4j start
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I read a forum and a guy said I need to re-insatll ubuntu again, I hope this is not the case?
Please HELP!!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think i have sorted it out using this command

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

I can now do

```
sudo -s
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Is this a good enough solution to the problem?

Comment: still getting error "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"

Comment: This is not a permanent solution. I had to re-install Obuntu

Comment: @MikeBarnes `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` this requires a password. How to get that password?

Comment: It would be your root account password

Comment: `pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers` try that @s4suryapal

Comment: `pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers`
`pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README`
This should work

Comment: pkexec chmod  755 /etc/sudoers this requires a password. i am logged  in using ssh key file i don't have root password then what i need to do?