# How to get phpmyadmin username and password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have intalled `phpmyadmin` recently in my system. Now I lost its username and password. I tried the below methods for login.

in `etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` I activated the *AllowNoPassword*

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

Comment: It means you have forgotten your root password, then read this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070401/mysql-root-password-forgotten

Comment: I also lost the username. Is there any way to get the username also?

Comment: "root" should be your username

Comment: Your username and password are located in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
 Step 1:

    Locate phpMyAdmin installation path.

    Step 2:

    Open phpMyAdmin>config.inc.php in your favourite text editor.

    Step 3:

    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
    $cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the following lines with new values

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'NEW_USERNAME';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NEW_PASSWORD';
```

Updated due to the absence of the above lines in the config file

Stop the MySQL server

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Start mysqld

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Login to MySQL as root

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Change MYSECRET with your new root password

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('MYSECRET') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```

Kill mysqld

```
sudo pkill mysqld
```

Start mysql

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Login to phpmyadmin as root with your new password

Comment: There is no option in my config file for user and password. But there is option for control user  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';
 I changed the control user but it's not working

Comment: I think the absence of those lines show that you username is root and you 'll have to change the root password in mysql server. I will edit my answer.

Comment: when I run the command sudo service mysql stop it shows the error            sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
stop: Unknown instance:                                                      is it because of the permission?

Comment: Yes this is a different problem. You should resolve this first.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951700/sudoers-is-world-writable-error

Answer (score 5):

Try opening config-db.php, it's inside /etc/phpmyadmin.
In my case, the user was phpmyadmin, and my password was correct.
Maybe your problem is that you're using the usual 'root' username, and your password could be correct.

Comment: I found it by these 2 commands on ubuntu 20.04 LTS:
`cd /etc/phpmyadmin`
`sudo vi config-db.php`

Comment: I simply looked in this file and used the $dbuser='phpmyadmin' as the username and $dbpass='mypwdwaslistedhere' as the password;

Answer (score 1):

> If you don't remember your password, then run this command in the Shell:

**mysqladmin.exe -u root password NewPassword**

where 'NewPassword' is your new password.

Comment: I also lost the username. Is there any way to get the username also?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with this. I didn't even create any passwords so I was confused. I googled it and I found out that I should just write **root** as username and than click GO. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: This assumes your root user doesn't have a password, and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I works for me In first run

Answer (score 0):

If you set the password while installing phpmyadmin.

The username will be phpmyadmin.

You can confirm the username & password in the

/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php [Check file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2mSl.png)

This is the file which is called/included in
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).