# How do I find the username and password of phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am unable to login into phpmyadmin. I have tried with username='root' and Password='null' and also have changed the config file.
Getting error " Cannot log in to the MySQL server "
How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get phpmyadmin username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354704/how-to-get-phpmyadmin-username-and-password)

Answer (score 0):

try this: [mysql root password reset](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/)