# How to fix this sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo, sudoers

I am working on AWS EC2 machine.
File permission of sudores file is,

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 902 Feb  5 12:22 sudoers`

There are various question on this , but these not works.
When i am trying to do,

`sudo chmod 444 sudoers`

This show error,

`sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

How to fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sudoers is world writable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951700/sudoers-is-world-writable-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated and discussed here

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-sudoers-syntax-errors-sudo/

Basically you detach the EBS volume from the EC2, mount it on another EC2, use root privs on that host to fix the file and then reattach it to the EC2

Comment: The link is broken. Updated one: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-sudoers-syntax-errors-sudo/

Answer (score 6):

Just run this 2 commands in terminal:

```
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: Code and commands are always handy, but some comments/context helps too. For example, why 0440?

Answer (score 1):

Running the below commands also helps.
Open two terminals in one terminal run the below command which gives pid

`echo $$`
2932433  ---->pid

In the other terminal with the pid obtained above run the following command

```
 pkttyagent --process 'pid from echo $$ command'
```

Now run `pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I have sorted it out using this command

`pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`

Then run

`sudo -s`

Finally, you will be

`root@ubuntu:~#`